# InvalidOperationException when trying to delete a share

Tags: c#, .net, wmi

I'm trying to delete a share but it keeps throwing InvalidOperationException on the "InvokeMethod" line. I'm new to WMI and I don't know if I'm missing something on my code... Can you help me please?

```
ManagementScope ms = new ManagementScope(@"\\localhost\root\cimv2");

ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = 
    new ManagementObjectSearcher(
        "Select * from Win32_Share where Name ='RanorexTests'");

ManagementObjectCollection result = searcher.Get();

((ManagementObject)result.GetEnumerator().Current).InvokeMethod(
    "Delete", new object[] { });
```

EDIT (full stacktrace):

> at
>   System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection.ManagementObjectEnumerator.get_Current()
>   at RanorexTests.CalculatorUnitTest.deleteShare() in
>   C:\RanorexSolution\RanorexTests\RanorexTests\FlashCalculator\CalculatorUnitTest.cs:line
>   126

Best regards,
Mourasman

Comment: post the entire stacktrace. this will provide the information to begin debugging. BTW: there are a number of reasons this failed. seeing the stacktrace will help narrow the possibilities. to get the full stack trace use `exception.ToString()`

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

this is the stacktrace:

at System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection.ManagementObjectEnumerator.get_Current()
   at RanorexTests.CalculatorUnitTest.deleteShare() in C:\RanorexSolution\RanorexTests\RanorexTests\FlashCalculator\CalculatorUnitTest.cs:line 126

Comment: please edit the post with this information, it will be much easier to everyone to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enumerators start with Current being null. You have to MoveNext() first.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.aspx:

> The foreach statement of the C# language (for each in Visual Basic) hides the complexity of the enumerators. Therefore, using foreach is recommended instead of directly manipulating the enumerator.
>
> Initially, the enumerator is positioned before the first element in the collection. The Reset method also brings the enumerator back to this position. At this position, calling the Current property throws an exception. Therefore, you must call the MoveNext method to advance the enumerator to the first element of the collection before reading the value of Current.

I usually just throw mine into a foreach loop even if I know there's only going to be one item in the collection:

```
foreach(ManagementObject obj in result)
  obj.InvokeMethod("Delete", new object[] { });
```

Comment: Confirmed, that fixed it! :) Thanks a lot!